# $(...).DataTable is not a function when using Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatable, laravel-mix

I struggle using Laravel Mix and DataTables. The issue I have is that when I compile down my .js-files etc., each time I would then visit a page that would execute a jQuery datatable, the follwoing error is thrown:

The error is:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).DataTable is not a function TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
```

From what I understand, `$(...).DataTable` is not a global variable, but how can I make sure that it is accessible "on a global scope" / within my app?

The following is my setup:

app.js

```
import jquery from 'jquery/dist/jquery.slim'
import 'bootstrap-sass'
import 'datatables.net';
import dt from 'datatables.net-bs';

window.$ = window.jQuery = jquery;
```

webpack.mix.js

```
mix
    .js('resources/assets/admin/js/app.js', 'js/')
    .extract([
        'jquery', 'bootstrap-sass', 'datatables.net', 'datatables.net-bs'
    ])
    .autoload({
        jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery', 'jquery'],
        DataTable : 'datatables.net-bs'
    })
```

Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check [datatables.net-bs npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/datatables.net-bs#npm). `var $ = require( 'jquery' );
require( 'datatables.net-bs' )( window, $ )`

Comment: same goes for **datatables.net**. From [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/datatables.net) `var $ = require( 'jquery' );
require( 'datatables.net' )( window, $ );`

Comment: I have tried that before and it caused this issue: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. Is there no way to import it?

Comment: Updated answer, `import $ from 'jquery';`

Comment: Or, in your case, `import $ from 'jquery-slim'`. I missed that's slim version

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT:** while this answer worked at the time that it was posted and accepted, looks like it's not the case anymore.
For anyone looking for the updated solution, other answers are up to date

[Yevgeniy Afanasyev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49991667/3226121)

[Alexander Gallego L.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53399793/3226121)

[Artistan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51107404/3226121)

Because this is accepted answer, I will add the new the solution, but the credit for this should go to people who provided updated answers

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require( 'jquery' );

require( 'datatables.net' );
require( 'datatables.net-bs' );
```

---

**Original answer**

Looking at npmjs pages for [datatables.net](https://www.npmjs.com/package/datatables.net) and the [datatables.net-bs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/datatables.net-bs#npm)

They should be initialized like this

```
var $ = require( 'jquery' );
require( 'datatables.net' )( window, $ );
require( 'datatables.net-bs' )( window, $ );
```

Which we could transform into this

```
var $     = require( 'jquery' );
var dt    = require( 'datatables.net' )
var dt_bs = require( 'datatables.net-bs' )

// in this call we're attaching Datatables as a jQuery plugin
// without this step $().DataTable is undefined
dt( window, $ )
// we need to do the same step for the datatables bootstrap plugin
dt_bs( window, $ )
```

But if you really want to use `import .. from ..`, take a look into [MDN import documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

```
import $ from 'jquery/dist/jquery.slim';
import * as dt from 'datatables.net';
import * as dt_bs from 'datatables.net-bs';

dt( window, $ )
dt_bs( window, $ )
```

Comment: I'm having the error with the first approach saying: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '$' of undefined

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev - i am having the same issue with most recent packages, any solution?

Comment: I posted my answer to this question.

Comment: This does not work. The module contains a self invoking function, all it returns is the datatable object the module attaches to the `$.fn` it tries to resolve automatically. So their documentation doesn't match their code. This self invoking function `require`s jquery itself, however, if I edit the datatables module, and assign the `require('jquery')` to the window object, the `jquery` module loaded by DataTables is not the instance of the module loaded by my main app.js. They appear not equal when compared with `===`.

Comment: @thephpdev, you are right. At the time of posting this answer, my code example worked, but I guess something changed since then. I've updated my answer. I hope other people who provided answer here don't mind that I used their solution as this was accepted answer. I gave them credit for that tho

Comment: After literal hours of trial and error, the following "worked." ```window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
require('datatables.net');
require('datatables.net-dt');```

Comment: @AlexBarker I've updated the answer for the `window.$ = window.jQuery = ...`

Answer (score 8):

**For the latest Laravel Mix...**

do not invoke the required datatable packages in webpack, [leave off the (...)](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/93380)

this will load bootstrap, jquery, datatables, and many of the plugins for datatables without any issues...

```
window._ = require( 'lodash' );;
window.$ = window.jQuery = require( 'jquery' );;
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;

// bootstrap
require('bootstrap');

// bootstrap datatables...
require( 'jszip' );
require( 'datatables.net-bs4' );
require( 'datatables.net-buttons-bs4' );
require( 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js' );
require( 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.js' );
require( 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js' );
require( 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js' );
require( 'datatables.net-autofill-bs4' );
require( 'datatables.net-colreorder-bs4' );
require( 'datatables.net-fixedcolumns-bs4' );
require( 'datatables.net-fixedheader-bs4' );
require( 'datatables.net-responsive-bs4' );
require( 'datatables.net-rowreorder-bs4' );
require( 'datatables.net-scroller-bs4' );
require( 'datatables.net-select-bs4' );
// bs4 no js - require direct component
// styling only packages for bs4
require( 'datatables.net-keytable' );
require( 'datatables.net-rowgroup' );
// pdfMake
var pdfMake = require('pdfmake/build/pdfmake.js');
var pdfFonts = require('pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts.js');
pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
```

no need for the other code in webpack.mix.js

```
.extract([
    'jquery', 'bootstrap-sass', 'datatables.net', 'datatables.net-bs'
])
.autoload({
    jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery', 'jquery'],
    DataTable : 'datatables.net-bs'
})
```

Comment: Man, You save my day. Works Great with Laravel-Mix 4.0.7, Datatables 1.10.19 and Datatables Buttons 1.5.6.

Comment: You save my day. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Solution (1)

This is how it worked for me:

```
require('datatables.net');
require('datatables.net-bs4');
```

Solution (2)

Below is how it was before and it was causing an error: "$(…).DataTable is not a function":

```
var a = require('../../../node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js');
var b = require('../../../node_modules/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js');
```

this is how I fixed it, but the top solution is obviously recommended

```
window.$.fn.DataTable = a;
window.$.fn.DataTable = b;
```

Please comment if you know the reasons behind the magic. Question is "why do direct links to js files work differently comparing to links to packages?"

Answer (score 2):

For all functions i load in bootstrap this:

```
try {
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

require('bootstrap');

window.JSZip = require("jszip");
//require( "pdfmake" );
require( 'datatables.net-bs4' );
require( 'datatables.net-buttons-bs4' );
require( 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.colVis.js' );
require( 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.flash.js' );
require( 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.html5.js' );
require( 'datatables.net-buttons/js/buttons.print.js' );
require( 'datatables.net-colreorder-bs4' );
require( 'datatables.net-fixedcolumns-bs4' );
require( 'datatables.net-responsive-bs4' );
require( 'datatables.net-rowreorder-bs4' );
require( 'datatables.net-scroller-bs4' );
require( 'datatables.net-keytable' );
require( 'datatables.net-rowgroup' );

} catch (e) {}
```

I work with Laravel 5.7 and npm 6.4.1

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add to Artistan's answer (I can't comment). I was able to get the CSV, Copy, and PDF buttons to appear using his code, but not the Excel button, until I changed this line

```
require( 'jszip' );
```

to this

```
window.JSZip = require('jszip');
```

After that, both the generic 'excel' and the 'excelHtml5' buttons appeared.

Comment: Thank you for this. Just wanted to add that when using 

`import JSZip from "jszip"`

you can just add

`window.JSZip = JSZip` 

after your imports to achieve the same result